# AsyncTaskDelegate Reference missing Asp.Net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to implement "PageAsyncTask" in asp.net 4.0.When i tried to declare "AsyncTaskDelegate" it showed a design time error.I checked the library reference.System.Web and Remoting are referenced but im still not able to figure out why it's missing.

And

AsyncMethodCaller caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(someMethod);
When i tried to invoke "caller.BeginInvoke" , Intellisense did not show me BeginInvoke nor EndInvoke.Am i missing any other library reference in my project?

Answer (score 2):

The `AsyncTaskDelegate` and `AsyncMethodCaller` classes doesn't exist in the BCL so there's nothing you could reference. Just copy their definition from the article/blog post you read about them.